# i have the mymenu.xml in res folder but when i inflate it, it says cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, menu

I created the menu folder under res, and created `mymenu.xml` inside the folder, and I can see the reserved memory space for mymenu in `R.java`
but it keeps prompting `cannot be resolved or is not a field.` What could be the problem?

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
    return true;

}
```

**in the R.java**

```
public static final class menu {
    public static final int mymenu=0x7f050000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're using your project's `R` not `android.R`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to rename it as menu.xml?
Can you show and the .xml source?

Comment: Please show your .xml code, and have you read and try this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Comment: i solved it, because it imported the R.java at some point, when i deleted the import, it worked...